# Using easyXDM (or any other client-side framework) for HTTP service availability tests (or response parsing in general) possible?

Tags: xss, easyxdm

I can't see from the [docs](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#the-easyxdmsocket) how it should work. Debugging with Firebug did not help either. Maybe I would have to sit for some hours to understand it better.

The basic problem is, that I'd like to **check the availability of various geo services (`WFS`,`WMS`)**. Due to the problem of XSS browser restrictions [`XmlHttpRequest`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) did not work.

I guess the `Socket` interface is the proper one to use, since I am not able to implement some `CORS` scenarios because I have no influence on the external services.

Using the following code works fine and returns some requested data (Firefox popup for the downloaded XML response):

```
var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
    remote: "http://path.to/provider/", // the path to the provider
    onReady:function(success) {
        alert(success);  // will not be called
    }
    onMessage:function(message, origin) {
        alert(message, origin);  // will not be called
    }
});
```

However I **did not find a way** (trying with the `onReady` and `onMessage` callbacks) to somehow **get to some HTTP `status` object** that I can process to determine which kind of response, **e.g. `200`, `404`**, I got.

Maybe it's the complete wrong way to solve this?

Comment: Trying to understand, do you want to check if the HTTP service is available programmatically?

Comment: via some website I like to build without a server-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly even my bounty did not help to get answers so I took a quick look around to gather some more infos on the issue myself...
First...

## the general problem of XSS

Looking at [XSS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Scripting) and some related issues/links discusses more the problems than solutions (which is ok).

Looking at the related **Firefox docs about the *JavaScript same-origin policy*** it becomes clear that our global slogan ***Security over Freedom***<sup>1</sup> is also applied in this area.
(Personally I don't like this way of solving the problem and would have liked to see another way to solve these problems as described at the end of this answer.)

<sup>1</sup>: nicely attributed [by Benjamin Franklins (founder of the US) statement](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Benjamin_Franklin): *He who sacrifices freedom for security deserves neither.*

## the CORS solution (=> external server dependencies)

The **only supported standard/robust way seems to be to use the *[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)* (*Cross Origin Resource Sharing*) functionality**.
Basically that means the **external server** has to **at least deliver** some *CORS*-compliant info (**HTTP Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`**) to allow others (= the client browser) to request data/content/.... Which also **means that if one does not have control over the external server there will be no general robust client-side/browser-way** to do this at all :-(.

## robust solution for server/client applications (if no external server control)

So if our external server does not support *CORS* or it is not configured to be usable by our requester *origin* (protocol/domain/port combination) it seems best to do this kind of access on our own applications server-side where we do not have these kinds of restrictions, but of course other implications.

## client-side solution I would have liked to see

Some introduction first to understand the client-side world I experience browsing the web as a standard user ...

I personally do not like to be tracked when browsing the web nor do I like to be slowed down with poor hardware or network resources nor do I want to get exposed to simply avoided data security issues when browsing the web. That's why I am using Firefox with various useful plugins like *RequestPolicy*, *AdBlock Plus*, *Ghostery*, *Cookie Monster*, *Flashblock* ... . This already shows a complexity, no average user usually could/would handle. But especially looking at *RequestPolicy* it shows how access to external resources can be handled on the client-side.

So if e.g. Firefox (without these plugins) would support some functionality to show the user a dialog similar to *RequestPolicy*, that could state something like the following, we could loosen the *one origin policy*:

```
  [x] 'http://srcdomain.com' (this site)
  [ ] all sites  (select to block/allow for all sites)

would like to request some data from 

  [x] 'http://dstdomain.com'
  [x] 'http://dst2domain.com' 

in a generally considered UNSECURE way.

You can selected one of the following options about how to proceed with
access to the selected sites from the selected sites:

  [x] block always (generally recommended)
  [ ] block only for this session
  [ ] allow always (but not to subreferences)  [non-recursively]
  [ ] allow only for this session (but not to subreferences)  [non-recursively]
  [ ] allow always (and all subreferences)  [recursively]
  [ ] allow only for this session (and all subreferences)  [recursively]
```

Of course this should be fomulated as clear as possible to the average user which I certainly did not do here and may be handled also by a default in the settings like the other existing technologies (Cookie Handling, JavaScript Handling, ...) do it.

This way I could solve the problem I have without much hassle, because I could nicely handle the amount of user setup required for this in my situation.

## answer regarding easyXdm

I guess since they recommend *CORS* as well and depend on the browsers this is the only robust way although some workarounds may still exist depending on browsers/versions/plugins like Flash and so on may exist.